# How does .headers().frameOptions().disable() work?

Tags: spring-security, h2

About `Spring Security` to let, control and get access to the `h2` web console

I read these two posts:

- [Spring Boot /h2-console throws 403 with Spring Security 1.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794721/spring-boot-h2-console-throws-403-with-spring-security-1-5-2)
- [H2 console and Spring Security - permitAll() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961270/h2-console-and-spring-security-permitall-not-working)

In conclusion is mandatory use the following ("improved" in someway):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            ...
            .mvcMatchers("/h2-console/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
            .and()
        .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
```

From above is better use `.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")` instead of `csrf().disable()` it for security reasons because the disable point applies only to `/h2-console/`, the latter is global and is not recommended.

Until here I am fine. And I am able to see the
H2 web console once the login process happened and the user has the required role.

[image]

Now is mandatory use `.headers().frameOptions().disable()`, if is not used happens the following:

[image]

The `localhost refused to connect` message appears to any inner block when the mouse's cursor is over any of them

My doubts are:

1. How does `.headers().frameOptions().disable()` work?
2. Is safe to use that sentence for Production Environment? Consider the difference between
   `.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")` and `csrf().disable()`, where the former is specific and the latter is "global" (and is not recommended). Therefore perhaps would be available a specific configuration much better than `.headers().frameOptions().disable()` (at a first glance for me is a "global" configuration) to only apply to `/h2-console/`
3. Could `.headers().frameOptions().disable()` have any negative effect, directly or indirectly, for other `configure(HttpSecurity http)` configuration? (Mostly for Production)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, let's look at the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) response header.
This header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`.
Sites can use this to avoid [Clickjacking](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html) attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

Spring Security sets the X-Frame-Options response header to `DENY` by default.
This tells the browser that the page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.
Since the H2 console UI is using `<frame>` elements, these will not be rendered and you will see the error screen that you shared in your question.

Spring Security allows you to customise this behaviour using `.headers().frameOptions()` in the Security DSL.
If you choose to disable the X-Frame-Options header (not recommended) by setting  `.headers().frameOptions().disable()`, then Spring Security will not add the X-Frame-Options header to the response.
This means your application could be rendered in a frame, and also could be **vulnerable to Clickjacking attacks**.

Instead of disabling it, it is sufficient to set X-Frame-Options to `SAMEORIGIN`, for this use case.

```java
http
    .headers(headers -> headers
        .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions
            .sameOrigin()
        )
    )
```

This tells the browser that the page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Since the frames in the H2 console UI (such as `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/tables.do`) are on the same origin as the the H2 console (`http://localhost:8080/h2-console`), the browser will allow them to be displayed.

However, if a different (potentially malicious) website tried to embed one the pages, the browser would not allow it.

Comment: Excellent explanation, just in case consider to share your snippet code in a non-lambda version too. Therefore both versions are available