# Problem while access to h2 with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, h2

I have a problem while I use H2 on web, my Spring Security is with JWT, everytime I have to access it appear this error:

[image: h2 web]

My code is look like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            // don't authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/h2/**").permitAll()
                // .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

But if I use this:
`authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()` it works, but I want just permitt to use `/h2/**` and not all paths.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```java
httpSecurity             
   .authorizeHttpRequests()
       .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .and()
   .csrf()
       .ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2/**")
       .and()
   .headers()
       .frameOptions().disable()
       .and()
   .headers(headers -> headers
                        .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions
                        .sameOrigin()
                        ));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does .headers().frameOptions().disable() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894268/how-does-headers-frameoptions-disable-work)

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana it didn't work, I added the code in my question